# Tool that changes permissions, and then changes them back

Tags: unix, permissions

I am looking for a tool that changes permissions, and then changes them back to a state before.

Comment: uhm ... can you be more specific? Maybe an example. Thx ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why?

Well..., with GNU stat

```
#!/bin/sh
orig_mode=$(stat -c %a "$2")
chmod "$1" "$2"
chmod "$orig_mode" "$2"
```

Here we go again, with *BSD stat this time:

```
#!/bin/sh
orig_mode=$(stat -f "%OMp%OLp" "$2")
chmod "$1" "$2"
chmod "$orig_mode" "$2"
```

With other versions of stat it would depend on whether/how output formatting is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Display a file's permissions with stat's "*-c,--format*" option combined with the "*%a Access rights in octal*" sequence. File permissions can be changed with *chmod*.

For example, save the original permissions of a file with stat.

```
$ OLD_PERM=$(stat -c"%a" $FILENAME)
$ echo $OLD_PERM
644
```

Change the permissions

```
$ chmod 600 $FILENAME
$ stat -c"%a" $FILENAME
600
```

And finally restore permissions back to the original value.

```
$ chmod $OLD_PERM $FILENAME
$ stat -c"%a" $FILENAME
644
```